# freeze a cout statement on the top of console window in c++?

Tags: c++, cout

Can anybody tell how we can freeze a cout statement on the top of console window in c++? i want to write a statement on the top of console window and want to pin it on the top, this statement will not scroll down with other statements.

Comment: C++ has no concept of console windows. You have to use a platform-dependent API. If you have any particular platform in mind, tag your question with its name.

Comment: `std::cout` goes to the standard output, which might not even be a console. What do you expect to happen when someone writes `YourApp.EXE > Output.TXT` ?

Comment: Sounds like you might want to use a text based user interface such as ncurses to do this.